# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. in @ManyToOne relation Hibernate, Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

it's my first post on StackOverflow. Sorry for my english. I have a problem with adding employees in the project Spring MVC and Hibernate. I run it on tomcat 7.047. I think the problem lies in the JSP or Hibernate database mapping. When I add a department in the same way it works. 
Oddzial and Pracownik relation in database:
Oddzial [or Department in English] 1 : n Pracownik[Employee]

Error output:

### HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report
message 
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

My Employee [Pracownik] class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pracownicy")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pracownik implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2556993070168215685L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer pracownik_id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="oddzial_id", nullable = false)
private Oddzial oddzial_id;
private String imie;
private String nazwisko;
private String adres_zamieszkania;
private String miasto;

@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('Pelny','Pol')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Etat etat;
private String stanowisko;
private Double pensja;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="kierownik_id", nullable = true)
private Pracownik kierownik_id;
//getters and setters generated by eclipse
}
```

My oddzial [Department] class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="oddzial")
public class Oddzial implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer oddzial_id;
private String miasto;
private String ulica;
//getters and setters generated by eclipse
}
```

My EmployeeController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/pracownik")
public class PracownikController {

@Autowired
private PracownikService pracownikService;

@Autowired
private OddzialService oddzialService;

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPracownikPage() {

    List<Oddzial> oddzialList = oddzialService.getOddzialy();       
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-pracownik-form");
    modelAndView.addObject("pracownik", new Pracownik());
    modelAndView.addObject("oddzialy", oddzialList);
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addingPracownik(@ModelAttribute Pracownik pracownik, HttpServletRequest request) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    pracownikService.addPracownik(pracownik);
    String message = "Pracownik was successfully added.";
    System.out.println(message);
    modelAndView.addObject("message", message);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

My JSP - adder of employee form:
I have used  and  and still the same.

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="pracownik" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pracownik/add.html">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Oddzial ID:</td>
    <td><form:radiobuttons path="oddzial_id" items='${oddzialy}'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Imię:</td>
    <td><form:input path="imie" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Nazwisko:</td>
    <td><form:input path="nazwisko" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pensja:</td>
    <td><form:input path="pensja" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Stanowisko:</td>
    <td><form:input path="stanowisko" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adres:</td>
    <td><form:input path="adres_zamieszkania" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
```

If you need more information please write.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Getter and setter for Oddzial and adres_Zamieszkania.

```
    public Oddzial getOddzial_id() {
    return oddzial_id;
}

public void setOddzial_id(Oddzial oddzial_id) {
    this.oddzial_id = oddzial_id;
}

    public String getAdres_zamieszkania() {
    return adres_zamieszkania;
}

public void setAdres_zamieszkania(String adres_zamieszkania) {
    this.adres_zamieszkania = adres_zamieszkania;
}
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to with mappings etc. It means the data send with the request could not be converted into whatever the handler method expects. I assume the culprit is *addingPracownik*? In that case check if your request payload can be converted to a Pracownik instance.

Comment: AddingPracownik method does not even start when I click submit.

Comment: Show your getters for `adres_zamieszkania` and `oddzial_id`.

Comment: public String getAdres_zamieszkania() {
  return adres_zamieszkania;}
 
 public void setAdres_zamieszkania(String adres_zamieszkania) {
  this.adres_zamieszkania = adres_zamieszkania;
 }


 public Oddzial getOddzial_id() {
  return oddzial_id;
 }

 public void setOddzial_id(Oddzial oddzial_id) {
  this.oddzial_id = oddzial_id;
 }

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Ok, now it should be in main post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has the following element

```
<form:radiobuttons path="oddzial_id" items='${oddzialy}'/>
```

which gets populated from

```
List<Oddzial> oddzialList = oddzialService.getOddzialy();       
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-pracownik-form");
modelAndView.addObject("pracownik", new Pracownik());
modelAndView.addObject("oddzialy", oddzialList);
```

This will create an html `<form>` `<input>` element for each object in the `oddziaList` `List`.  The `value` attribute's value will come from the `toString()` method of the `Oddzial` class. Regardless of what that value is, unless you have a `Converter` to convert from the return value of the `toString()` to an object of type `Oddzial`, Spring will be unable to make the conversion itself and will therefore give you a 400 Bad Request.

You have two options:

1. Implement and register a custom `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` to do the conversion.
2. Change the `<form:radiobuttons>` to a `c:forEach>` containing regular `<input type="radio">` elements that contain the id of the `Oddzial` objects. In your controller, use that submitted ID to find the appropriate `Oddzial` object and set it on the `Pracownik` object before submitting it to your service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used 2 version of solution and it works! Thanks!